# HTML5 code templates (like C++)?

Tags: html

Lets say I have HTML like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <p><a href="#" onclick="play('image1')" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Play Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Official Link</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

which is basically one of many entries where only few things change, in this instance only "image1" will be replaced by something else in each entry. Is there a way to make a template out of it like:

```
<template param="%image%">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/%image%.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <p><a href="#" onclick="play('%image%')" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Play Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Official Link</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which I then can just use like

```
<template-instance param="%image%=image1.jpg" />
<template-instance param="%image%=image2.jpg" />
```

etc...

Please don't ride on the syntax & the code I am trying to template, since its just an example. But I encounter countless of opportunities to create such templates, because its just the normal "Programming Approach". Right now HTML to me feels as if I had a programming language that does only support "#include <>" but has no procedure or classes etc... Since I can't imagine that someone would create such a language I think I missed out on something big here.

Ah yeah, as the tag implies I don't care about legacy code. HTML5 will be the minimal requirement and pending specifications are also fine. I am only interested in bleeding edge here ;).

Comment: You might be interested in [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/). Here you can define custom tags with all the behaviour you want. Much more powerful than you need it, but may be worth a look.

Comment: @Sirko: Hmm yeah that sounds quite good. Even though I still hope hTML5 would have something maybe not quite as powerful at least, implemented already.

Comment: The stuff in Polymer is on its way towards the standard HTML5 implementations. Chrome, e.g., supports a large bunch of that stuff natively. Basically Polymer is kind of a polyfill/shim until everything has landed in all the important browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTML5 feature for import. You can see an article on it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/).

In fact, it just uses `script` or `link` tags to `import` a template. You can clone them and append them to a node in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see the idea of Polymer but it seems a bit overkill for me atm. I now wrote this nice little function which can do whatever I need:

```
function instanciateTemplate(name, params, applyTo)
{
    $.ajax({url: "templates/" + name + ".html", dataType: "text", type: "GET"}).done(function(src) 
    { 
        for(var e in params) {
            src = src.split(e).join(params[e]);
        }       
        document.getElementById(applyTo).innerHTML = src;
    });
}

var buttons = ["B", "X", "A", "Y", "L", "R", "Left", "Right", "Up", "Down", "Start", "Select"];
for(var i in buttons)
{
    var btn = buttons[i];
    instanciateTemplate("controllerAssign", {"%KEY%": btn}, "edit_" + btn);
}
```

It basically just reads arbitraty HTML which in this case contains various "%KEY%" markers, replaces the markes with the defined replacements and then assigns the whole thing to an arbitrary given container DIV or whatever element. Pretty simple but powerful enough.